# Loop through HTML table for specific dropdown value

Tags: jquery, html-table, html-select

I have a table which has 3 sections (section1, section2, section3), now inside the dropdown, user will select any of the above mentioned sections, and add record, now the table will have all the records for each sections.

I want to just loop through table for specific section like only for section1. I am currently able to loop through all the checked rows (using checkbox) but now i want to loop through that specific section only.

Here's what I am doing for looping through checked rows:

```
$.each($("input[type=checkbox]:checked"), function (index, item) {
    .... my code here.
}
```

### UPDATE

[image]

From the above table, we have category as gear/artists/lessons, as you can see each has 3 records, highlighted in different colors, now i want to fetch data for specific dropdown items, like rows of all lessons etc.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: i am stuck with looping through table which has specific sections selected only, in dropdown $.each($("input[type=checkbox]:checked [something here to check for specific item selected in dropdown]"), function (index, item) {

Comment: So the dropdown includes every record from section1/2/3 but you only want the selected section records to appear in dropdown?

Comment: Can you give us your table ?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

There are a severel solution, you can simply check the value in your loop like this :

```js
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(index, item) {
    var $tr = $(item).closest("tr");
    var $select = $tr.find("select");
    if ( $select.val() === "section1" ) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

**EDIT : pre filter with grep**

An other solution to do that is to store in array your matched elements with **grep** function, like this :

```
var array = $.grep( $("input[type=checkbox]:checked"), function(index, elem) {
    var $tr = $(item).closest("tr");
    var $select = $tr.find("select");
    return ( $select.val() === "section1" );
});
```

Comment: Can we not do it in the single loop, because i want to check the ordinal value of previous row, now if previous row is of different category, i would end up getting wrong ordinal, so plan was to loop through specific category and find match the current oridinal with the previous ordinal

Comment: @Abbas I edit my answer, in the filled array, you get only the checkbox checked of the specific section, know you just had to loop throug this array to do something with these elements.